# Install Magento in directory

Tags: installation

Good Morning
I have uploaded (for test) all the Magento files in a directory (magento) because in the root I have installed my official domain.

When I open magento in the browser (http://www.mydomain.ext/magento) instead the installation process this error is displayed:
**500 Internal Server error**

Maybe magento does not support installation in a dir ?
I should perhaps modify some configuration files?

Thank for Help
Gaetano

Comment: Iwawa, check your server logs and show us related error message.

Answer (score 1):

It does support it, so the problem must be somewhere else. It could be a problem with your `.htaccess` file, you can check it like this:

1. Rename .htaccess to .htaccess.bak
2. open http://www.mydomain.ext/magento/index.php/install

Still see the error? Check your server logs or ask your hoster if you don't know where they are / don't have access to them.